# How to use digest auth in python asyncio?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio, python-3.7

This is my source

```
import sqlalchemy
import asyncio
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

async def test(ip):
    auth = HTTPDigestAuth("username", "password")
    url = f"http://{ip}?action=param1"
    request = loop.run_in_executor(None, requests.get, url, auth)
    response = await request
    print(response.content)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(test("127.0.0.1"))
```

This is required digest auth.
Error : Authentication Error: Access Denied, Authorization required.
But I can't understand my source solution....

How can I solve this problem?
How to use digest auth in Python asyncio???

sorry, I can't speak English well...

Comment: Note that your question is not about asyncio, but about the `requests` library which implements HTTP. With asyncio you shouldn't use requests anyway because then your program isn't async, it just uses threads under the hood. The [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/) client claims to support digest authentication, so that's what I'd recommend to try.

Comment: Thanks!!!
What I was looking for  is httpx(pkg).

Comment: But, httpx is a beta version, not an official library.
I am making programming for government agencies, so I am uneasy about the beta version of the library.

Comment: I understand your concern, and while you will best know what your employers require, do keep one thing in mind. All popular Python libraries, including `requests`, `aiohttp` and `numpy`, and even `asyncio` and Python itself, are open-source and not really "official" in any way that would be recognized by a government agency. And yet they are widely used and very useful. If you were to discard open source libraries for not being formally approved, you wouldn't get very far. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks. httpx work very well!!!